# Расчет оценок/рейтинга как PlayMarket'е

Tags: javascript, математика

[image]

как собственно осуществляется расчет? как они вывели 3,5? по какой формуле?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По этой:

[image: Расчёт рейтинга]

На `js` это закодить не проблема

Это называется [среднее арифметическое взвешенное](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)

**UPD**. По вашей картинке

[image: формула расчёта]

И округлить получившийся результат

Comment: можете привести пример по моей картинке? не совсем понятно